# Insert trigger on a table with extra constant column in to new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, updates

I've been working on a database which consists of two schemas names as front and backup. Where in one table name:

```
front.Details

studID SemID GPA
100     1     4
200     2     3
```

Another table name is:

```
backup.DetailsV
studID  DEPT SemID GPA
```

The output in Table backup.DetailsV should look like below:

```
studID  DEPT SemID GPA
100      1     1    4
200      1     2    3
100      2     1    4
200      2     2    3
```

How can I create trigger on table Details to insert in to table DetailsV twice with dept id 1 and 2?

Comment: Why do you need a physical table and a trigger? Why isn't a view that adds this column sufficient?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:I dont get your question.My problem is if there is a new insert in details table the new row must be inserted in to DetailsV table which has one extra column.The new record must be inserted twice with deptID 1 AND deptID 2.

Comment: And I was asking why this table needs to exist at all? I can create a view that, for every row in `Details` produces two rows which only differ in that one has a `deptID` value of `1`, and the other `2`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever :There is a stored proc designed in such a way that it is accesing DetailV table.And there will be lot of data will be inserted from another tables in to DetailV table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue Damien's thought, if the only reason to have the DetailsV table is to generate that output, you can easily do that with a view. If it is just reading data, the stored procedure doesn't know or care if the source is a table or a view.

```
Select studID, 1 as Dept, SemID, GPA
From front.Details
UNION ALL 
Select studID, 2 as Dept, SemID, GPA
From front.Details
```

You would only keep a backup table if you needed to keep a history of the data flowing through the front.Details table, or if you needed to manipulate that data before reporting it out. If that is really what you want, the trigger query is very similar, but instead of addressing the table, you use the special [inserted] table to get the new values.

```
Select studID, 1 as Dept, SemID, GPA
From inserted
UNION ALL 
Select studID, 2 as Dept, SemID, GPA
From inserted
```